# Installing Mysql gem on OSX error - 'Marshal data too short'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

Getting a 'marshal data too short' error when trying to install the mysql gem on OSX.  Poking around I've heard suggestions to clear out .gems, but can't seem to locate it on the system.  Can anyone offer help?

```
apple$ sudo gem install mysql --backtrace --debug
Exception `NameError' at /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:161 - uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
Exception `Gem::LoadError' at /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:826 - Could not find RubyGem test-unit (>= 0)

Exception `ArgumentError' at /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:111 - marshal data too short
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    marshal data too short
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:111:in `load'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:111:in `fetch_spec'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:71:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:70:in `map'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:70:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:99:in `find_gems_with_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:192:in `find_spec_by_name_and_version'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:213:in `install'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:118:in `execute'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115:in `execute'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/command.rb:257:in `invoke'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:132:in `process_args'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:102:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:58:in `run'
    /usr/bin/gem:21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error on my windows machine, If I would use gem.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)    
marshal data too short
```

To delete the gem cache directory "c:\Documents and Settings\MyUser\.gem" worked for me.
It seems that some data are saved even if you reinstall ruby. Probably a cached file was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below command  . Provide the location of the mysql directory in your OS X .

sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql

http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/

Check the link for installing Mysql  on Mac OSX  if you haven't correctly installed .

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Also, the `.gem` directory is located in your home directory: `/Users/yourname/.gem`

Hope that helps.